# JavaScript 'this' driving me nuts

Tags: javascript, this

I frequently use [Visualize](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) to figure out scope, function call sites, and all, while I advance my JS learning escalade. Recently I bumped into this:

```js
function foo() {
    console.log( this.a );
}

var a = 2;

function bar() {
    var a = 5;
    foo();
};

bar();
```

Google Chrome gives me a 2 in the console, while I was expecting a 5 (`foo`'s call site). Interesting enough, pythongtutor (under JS, of course) gives me an error message of undefined, as seen below:

[image: pytontutor after executing code]

I have two questions:

1. Why the outcome is 2 and not 5 since, calling site for foo is within bar where a is 5.
2. Why is pythontutor flagging and error?

Comment: @Xufox `this` refers to the context that was set during the function call (either explicitly or implicitly). It has no connection to where the function was defined.

Comment: Ok, pythontutor must be under strict mode. That's all. But the first question still applies.

Comment: @FernandoSoares because `var a = 5;` is a local variable. Local variables never available through property access of any object.

Comment: "Context" is an object, not the whole "scope". It literally is some object.

Comment: @Xufox, check Kyle Simpson's YDNJS - this & Object Prototypes. You are mistaken.

Comment: @Xufox: `this` doesn't refer to scope, nor does it relate to where the function is defined.

Answer (score 5):

> 1) Why the outcome is 2 and not 5 since, calling site for foo is within bar where a is 5.

The *site* of a call has no effect whatsoever on `this` in JavaScript. *How* you call the function and how that function is defined (e.g., is it a bound function, an arrow function, or just a plain function or method) are all that matters.

> 2) Why is pythontutor flaggin and error?

Because in strict mode, it would be an error.

When you do:

```
foo();
```

...you're not setting any explicit `this` for the call. If `foo` is a plain function (and yours is), that means that in loose mode, `this` will refer to the global object during the call to `foo`, and see the global object's `a` property on `this.a` (and the global `a`'s value is 2). In strict mode, `this` will be `undefined`, so `this.a` is an error (trying to read `a` from `undefined`).

Separately, the `a` local variable in `bar` isn't accessible as a property of **any** object.*

Related:

- [*How does the “this” keyword work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

---

* Gory details: Conceptually at a specification level, it's a binding held in the variable environment record (notionally an object) for the execution context of the call to `bar` (also notionally an object), but that's conceptual. We can't access environment record objects or execution context objects from code, and in a given implementation, they may not literally exist.

Comment: "is a plain function" --- what does "plain" here mean?

Comment: @zerkms: I thought I'd made that clear by contrast: Not bound or arrow.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought as well. It's unfortunate there is no a dedicated name for it :-(

Comment: @zerkms: Yeah. I reworded slightly to make that bit clearer. I've heard "plain", "normal", and I've uncreatively used "`function` function" (but that doesn't really make sense, as methods aren't declared with `function` but are "plain" in this regard...sigh!).